# how to configure windows change password policy on linux

Tags: linux, authentication, samba

I work in a linux system with a windows proxy account. The password must change aways at the end of the month. Nowdays i need to go to a windows machine, change my password and go back to my linux machine.

The password is used for others internal services too. (like private email, git access, database access, etc).

I want to change my password without the help of a windows. I want to do it on linux. It can be done?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://superuser.com. Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites.Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more questions.
 Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

This is really the wrong forum: I'd suggest trying [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

SUGGESTION:

It sounds like [smbpasswd](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbpasswd.8.html) might be a solution: http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Site suggestions are comments, not answers.